# iptables openvpn forward selectively from eth to tun

Tags: tunnel, iptables, openvpn

*Simple for those who know, indecipherable for those who don't...*

I'm running openVPN on (hypothetical) 66.66.66.66, I want to FORWARD incoming traffic, arriving on interface eth0 to interface tun0.

It would also be nice to filter - based on destination IP address. I'm doing the NAT later on, but like to lock down early wherever possible.

So onto the main course...

This works:

```
  #Enable forwarding from eth0 to tun0
  iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
```

But this doesn't pass any packets whatsoever:

```
 #Stricter version
 iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ --dst 66.66.66.66  -j ACCEPT
```

Am I being unacceptably foolish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works quite well for me, I'm not sure if it's perfect but seems sane enough.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ \! -d 178.79.178.75 -j DROP
```

Comment: Oh yeah, you must also enable martians in sysctl on the remote box